# Can rocket candy explode during the preparation?

Tags: home-experiment, fuel, explosives

I would like to follow the steps in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyPysthIRss

After I mixed the `Potassium nitrate KNO3` and the `sugar`, I start to cook it in a pot, and stir it very often. After 25-30 min, the KNO3 and the sugar will melt together, and become a brown mass.

My question is: Can this mixture explode during the heating somehow? Or it can just burn, not explode? How to prevent it, and do it the most secure way?

Comment: If it's brown, it may be too hot. Do you use a temperature probe? in my case it didn't get significantly dark. You are caramelizing the sugar... that's too hot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See James Yawn's website [${\it Recrystalized\; Rocketry}$](http://www.jamesyawn.net/), which is all about solid propellant rocketry of the type you're interested in. It's really an exceptionally comprehensive site.

> Can this mixture explode during the heating somehow?

It appears that it's more likely to catch fire, and do so rather vigorously, as in cases where it's exposed to a spark or an open flame. Because the system (pan and mixture of $\ce{KNO3}$ and sugar) would be open to the atmosphere (and not confined to a fixed volume), there's more of a risk of fire than of an explosion. As reported by [James Yawn in the subsection on "Skillet Rcandy"](http://www.jamesyawn.net/skillet/large/index.html):

> This stuff looks innocent enough in the pan.  But if you have ever seen a quantity this size burn you will have more respect for it.  This batch could send a tongue of flame 20 feet in the air and engulf the person stirring it, if only briefly.  Burns to the body would likely be second degree, and I am willing to tolerate that level of risk.  But eyeballs don't recover from this kind of trauma easily.

See [this safety page from James Yawn's site](http://www.jamesyawn.net/rcandy/safety.htm).

> Or it can just burn, not explode?

Yes, it can just burn: that's essentially what's going on in the rocket engine. The exhaust from the burn is channeled in one direction (${\it via}$ the hollow core in the engine itself), resulting in thrust in the other direction.

> How to prevent it, and do it the most secure way?

From [James Yawn's site](http://www.jamesyawn.net/rcandy/safety.htm):

> **Basic Safety Precautions**
>
> At present, I do NOT recommend making this propellant in a household kitchen.
>
> Make small batches only!  No more than one standard recipe, which yields about 160 grams of propellant.
>
> Wear protective gear. You should have a full-face shield, long sleeved heavy cotton shirt, heavy apron and heat-resistant gloves.  These must be worn at appropriate points in the process.
>
> Do not allow children or rambunctious pets in the room where you are working.
>
> Do not allow distracting, inattentive, inebriated or otherwise incompetent adults in the room, especially if they smoke.
>
> Be vigilant of possible sources of sparks, flame, or high temperature that could ignite propellant on contact.
>
> If you smoke, place your cigarettes and lighter in another room so you will not light up unconsciously.
>
> Clear your work-area of any flammable materials.
>
> Have a good fire extinguisher available. Also a 5-gallon bucket of water nearby and a garden hose outside.
>
> Make sure there is good ventilation, and a quick escape route to fresh air.
>
> Avoid stupid rocket tricks.
>
> Avoid excessive exposure to Potassium Nitrate.

All of the above points are elaborated upon at the linked page.