# What is the compound I made from KNO3 and table sugar which subsequently exploded when I exposed it to a flame?

Tags: explosives

I mixed 75% $\ce{KNO3}$ and 25% $\ce{C12H22O11}$ (by volume) in boiling water to make slow burn fuses. Some of the product became a thick brown paste.

After drying, a hard cake of an approximate 1 tablespoon amount exploded when lit. What compound did I make?

Comment: [Rocket candy](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35522/can-rocket-candy-explode-during-the-preparation).

Answer (score 2):

It's not a new compound - it's just an intimate mix of fuel (sugar) plus oxidiser (nitrate). It's not the most stable of situations to have...